# Should the change event be fired when text field's value is changed both manually and programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery UI Autocomplete text field with a remote datasource. The autocomplete's `select` event does three things:

1. Updates the text field's value with the one selected from the autocomplete list
2. Makes an AJAX call to load some more data into the page
3. Moves focus to another text field (created in the previous step)

The text field also has a `change` event that removes the data loaded in step 2 above and triggers the autocomplete's `search` event.

This works perfectly in IE (tested with versions 9 and 10), but not in Firefox. When I make a selection from the autocomplete list, the extra data is never shown (though analysing the network traffic shows that the AJAX call is being made) and the autocomplete's `search` event is triggered. I managed to track the problem down to Firefox triggering the text field's `change` event after step 3 above, apparently because I typed something into the text field to trigger the autocomplete list, and despite the fact that the text field was later updated programmatically.

Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/2umrJ/1
(For the sake of brevity that example just uses a `keyup` event on the text field.)

Output in IE10:

> input1.focus() triggered
>   input1.blur() triggered
>   input2.focus() triggered

Output in Firefox 20:

> input1.focus() triggered
>   input1.change() triggered
>   input1.blur() triggered
>   input2.focus() triggered

As can be seen, Firefox fires the `change` event while IE doesn't. Now I know that by default (i.e. without any extra code) the `change` event is only triggered when the value was changed manually, but what is the correct behaviour when the value is changed *both manually and programmatically* without the field losing focus in between?

Also, more importantly for my particular case, if Firefox's behaviour is correct (or at least not incorrect), what's the best way to prevent it? I don't want the `change` event to be triggered when focus is being changed programmatically, after I selected something from the autocomplete list.

Comment: Curiously enough, Firefox only fires the `change` event once. In the JSFiddle above, subsequent keypresses in the first text field only trigger `input1.blur()` and `input2.focus()`. That can't be right, can it?

Comment: I also checked the fiddle in opera and chrome - neither fire the change event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2umrJ/2/  Look at my updated fiddle and you'll understand why it was only firing once. (Hint - bar == bar)

Comment: @Zach That makes sense, thanks. I guess I expected Firefox to completely ignore programmatical changes and always update if the value has been changed manually, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the change event from triggering in firefox, I would have something in your logic that sets a variable stating it's being changed programatically and in the change event logic, you should check that variable, don't execute the change logic if it's programatically triggered, and reset the variable before exiting.

Comment: This was what I ended up doing. I was hoping there was a more elegant way to do this, or maybe a better way to wire up the events, but this works well enough. Thanks!